# Adding recessed lights to existing ceiling fan connection

Tags: electrical, lighting, ceiling-fan

I replaced an old ceiling fan in my sons room that had a light fixture and dimmer switch.  The new ceiling fan only operates with a remote that it came with.  No pull strings for the light or fan.  I also want to add a couple of recessed lights so he gets more light as the fan light fixture does not give off much light.

Currently I have a armored electrical cable in the ceiling with Red/Black/White.  The new ceiling fan remote receiver has red/white cable on one side and on the other, blue, black, white.  I ran romex cable to the recessed cans and attached them together matching the white/black/and bare.  I have the cable for the recessed lights in the same ceiling hole for the the fan ready.  How do I make the connection so that the recessed lights work with a dimmer switch and the fan and fan light work with the remote it came with?  We will used the recessed lighting and fan 99% of the time, and rarely use the fan light.

In the switch box, I see the armored red joined with the black from the electrical panel run.  The armored black is by itself currently as I took off the old dimmer switch.   And the armored white is joined with the other white from the electrical panel run.

This is a picture of my switch box. The black/red/white on the right side are the armored cable to ceiling fan.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

#### At the Light

- Connect the white wire that leads to the recessed lights, and the white wire from the fan/light to the white wire in the ceiling box.
- Connect the the black from the recessed lights, to the black ungrounded (hot) wire that's controlled by the dimmer.
- Connect the red wire from the fan/light, to the red ungrounded (hot) wire that is not controlled by the dimmer.
- Connect all the grounding conductors.

#### At the switch

- Connect the LINE wire (probably black, but depends on manufacturer) from the dimmer, in with the black wire from the feeder cable.
- Connect the black wire from the armored cable, to the switched (probably red) wire from the dimmer.
- Connect the ground wire from the dimmer, with the other grounds in the box.

This should allow the dimmer to control the recessed lights, and the remote to control the fan/light.

Of course this assumes that power comes to the switch first, and one of the wires in the cable is always hot.

Based on the info you've provided, it should look something like this.

[image]

---

According to the documentation for the dimmer, the black lead is LINE and the red lead is LOAD.

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40653/discussion-on-answer-by-tester101-adding-recessed-lights-to-existing-ceiling-fan).

Comment: Didn't have time until today.  Going to take down the fan again and try what you stated

Comment: So everything was working once again while down.  I put it up and then the recessed light stood on with no dimmer control.  I played around with the fan ceiling mount and noticed that when I pushed up, light remained on.  If I pulled down, light worked with dimmer.  Only exposed cable in the ceiling box was the ground so I taped them up and pushed everything up again, and it worked.  Problem is, I turned the dimmer switch on and off a couple of times and it blew it out.  Fan still works, but dimmer is fried.

Comment: That's scary.   I think it might be time to call in some local help.

Comment: I'm going to run 1 additional romex from the switch box to the recessed lights and tie in that cable to the black and white.

Comment: If you have the ability to run a new cable, I'd run a new 3 wire cable, to replace the armored cable altogether.

Comment: 3 wire romex like 14/3?

Comment: Yes. If you're using 14 AWG wire and a 15 ampere breaker, 14/3 with ground.

Comment: I ran the cable from the recessed lights to switch box.  What should the wiring be in there now to get power to the recessed lights and dimmer switch?

Comment: @tekaddict you went direct from the switch to the lights?  Sorry about my earlier advise to use 14/3, I thought you were just replacing the armored cable. If you went direct to the lights, you'll connect the white to the bundle of whites in the switch box.  Then connect the black from the light, to the red LOAD wire off the dimmer.

Comment: How about the black cable on the dimmer?  Gets connected to live feed bundle?

Comment: My thought process was to run that addition romex to the recessed lights and get power to them and switch seperate from the armored cable.  Just leave the armored cable for the ceiling fan like the previous fan.  So I put a dimmer switch in, black from dimmer to breaker feed bundle, red from dimmer to black from the last romex run I did, and joined the white from the last romex run to all the other whites in switch box.  Turned breaker on and dimmer blew again.  This time, armored cable was not connected to anything.  I have fan off for now

Comment: How are the recessed lights wired?  It's all black to black, and white to white, right? How many recessed lights are there, and what's the wattage of each one? Are the bulbs LED, CFL, or incandescent?

Comment: 4 recessed lights.  Says 11 watt LED (60 watt equiv.)

Comment: http://m.homedepot.com/p/Commercial-Electric-5-in-and-6-in-White-Recessed-LED-Trim-with-2700K-90-CRI-CER6730DWH27/204726945

Comment: And yes, black to black and white to white between the recessed cans

Comment: I've done about all I can do, from this side of the internet. You might have to get somebody in to stick in some probes, and poke around a bit. There's definitely something funky, but I can't see it from here

Comment: thanks.  Called a couple but no one available yet.  Im thinking job is too small to make them come right away.  Do you think it's best to run a new romex and add a new breaker in the panel just for the recessed lights?

Comment: @tekaddict do you have any idea where the other 14/3 cable goes, and how it's terminated?  Are you sure you wired the recessed lights properly?

Comment: that's my next step.  Going to remove that additional 14/3 romex from the bundle.  I believe that is the connection to my older sons room as both rooms are on the same breaker.  As far as the lights, I believe it's all correct.  I did them the same way I did my other rooms.  Cable one can to the other matching the white and black.  On the last can in the chain, one romex run to the switch for power.  Everything turns on when I flip the breaker on but as soon as I slide the dimmer switch on or off or play with the dim slider, the switch burns out

Comment: I found 1 outlet in his room that has the red connected.  That's the 2nd romex with 3 wires.  Should I disconnect that red and cap it and just connect the black to the outlet?  Can that be causing the dimmer switch to blow?  It was the outlet with his window A/C connected.

Comment: so testing this even what I found is that my other sons room power rides on the 2 wire romex.  The room I'm working in has 3 outlets that are connected to the second romex with 3 wires.  So to test, I disconnected that 2nd romex with 3 wires (leaving the 3 outlets dead), connected the ceiling fan to the 2 wire romex and the ceiling fan worked.  I then joined the recessed lighting romex feed in and connected the dimmer.  Turned on the breaker, and turned on the switch, breaker tripped.  This is with the 3 wire romex disconnected.

Comment: @tekaddict Check the wiring for the recessed lights.  That's the only load on the dimmer, and the only part of the circuit that's causing problems.

Comment: just checked all 4 recessed cans.  Whites are with white and black with black on all cans.

Comment: It turns out it was one of the recessed cans causing the short.  Swapped it out, and no issues.

Answer (score 1):

The issue turned out to be a bad recessed can.  I removed added one can at a time to the chain until I found which was causing the switch to short.  Replaced that can and all 4 lights are working.

Comment: You can choose this as your preferred answer to your question (you may have to wait a day).

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, you have black wire which has constant power and it doesnt work by any switch. You can connect your fan to the black, white and ground wires. Leaving the red out. Now you can use the red wire to connect some recessed lights and i assume that red wire will control by the switch.

For the fan you will have to use remote to turn it on and off.

Comment: The OP already answered his question (indicating that there was a bad light fixture) 6 years ago. There's no need for another answer.